# postgresql employee inherits manager data for missing values

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm trying to write SQL to fill the missing values for an employee. A manager is also an employee. Values missing for an employee can be inherited from manager, if values are not there for an employee's manager, then will lookup to manager's manger ( have to look upto root manager if required, till we get values) values.

Below is table and data

```
create table employee(
employee_id int primary key,    
name text,
manager_id int,
department text,
lob text);

insert into employee
(employee_id,name,manager_id,department,lob)
values
(12,'a',null,'IT','BFI'),
(3,'b',12,'sales',null),
(4,'c',3,null,'Banking'),
(6,'d',12,null,null),
(7,'e',4,null,null),
(10,'f',7,null,null);
```

[image]

sample data is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28fda3fec2e689b42049e51d6f43497c)

example: employee_id=4 has department = null and manager_id=3 and lob=Banking, here department is null for this employee, so query  will have to inherit `department` value from employee's manager.

employee_id=4's manager is 3 and has department = sales.
now expected result for employee 4 is

[image]

Similarly have to inherit values for `lob` column to replace nulls for each employee.

Example: neither employee 10  nor his manager 7 doesn't have `department` and `lob` value, but employee/manger 7 has manager  4 and manager 4 has `lob` value Banking and `department` value sales inherit from his manager.
So employee 10 and employee 7 will inherit `department` and `lob` values Sales and Banking.
Expected result for employee 10 is

[image]

my query

```
with RECURSIVE inherit_parent_values as (
select * from employee
where employee_id=10
union
select e.manager_id,p.name,p.manager_id,
coalesce(e.department,p.department),
coalesce(e.lob,p.lob)
from employee p inner join
inherit_parent_values e 
ON e.manager_id=p.employee_id)

select * from inherit_parent_values
```

Trying using recursive query but this is giving all managers rows upto root level of each employee instead of one row for each employee.

Also have to get not null values in column level. seems coalesce is not useful in my query

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to fill employee null values from managers ?

Expected result is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=164761d1a1a2b86b5bc09bbfae6f921d)

You did it bottom-up (starting with the leaf - an employee), I'd do it top-down (starting at the root - a top-manager):

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM employee
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT 
        e.employee_id,
        e.name,
        e.manager_id,
        COALESCE(e.department, r.department) as department,
        COALESCE(e.lob, r.lob) as lob
    FROM employee e
    JOIN rec r ON r.employee_id = e.manager_id
)
SELECT * FROM rec
```